# Does a median always exist for a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, median

Does a median always exist for a random variable?

Note that a median of a random variable $X$ is defined as a number $m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(X \leq m) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \geq m) \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What would need to hold for a median _not_ to exist?

Comment: It always exists but sometimes it might have more than one value.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: by its definition, that is the best I can say now.

Comment: @John.Mathew: Why does it always exist?

Comment: If both conditions were not true you would have a contradiction since you know that either $X(\omega)\le m$ or $X(\omega) \ge m$ for any $m$.

Comment: It might not exist if $X$ is a random variable with complex values or if $X$ takes values in $\{\text{red}, \text{green}, \text{blue}\}$.  A median needs an order for your definition to be meaningful

Comment: @copper.hat what does this argument bring a contradiction?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical The sum of probabilities of $X(\omega) \le m$ and $X(\omega) \ge m$ must add up to at least one.

Comment: @copper.hat braindead for a second. Forgive me.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical I did not establish the existence of a median, in fact, now that I look at I am not sure what my comment was about, it may have been a response to a subsequently deleted comment or I may have had too much wine. The answer by Srivatsan establishes the existence.

Comment: @copper.hat agree. I deleted my previous reply which got denied by myself but now turns out actually correct. Thx for the discussion!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I will assume that $X$ is finite w.p. $1$. Then we claim that $m := \sup \ \{ a \mid P(X \geqslant a) \geqslant \frac12 \}$ is always a median. We just need to verify the two defining properties:

- For $a > m$, from the definition of $m$, the tail probability $P(X \geqslant a)$ is strictly less than $\frac12$. Now since $\lim \limits_{a \to m+} P(X \geqslant a)$ exists and equals $P(X \gt m)$, it follows that $P(X \gt m) \leqslant \frac12$. That is, $P(X \leqslant m) \geqslant \frac12$.
- For the other direction, we reverse the above argument. For any $a \lt m$, we have $P(X \geqslant a) \geqslant \frac12$. Now since $\lim \limits_{a \to m-} P(X \geqslant a) = P(X \geqslant m)$, it follows that $P(X \geqslant m) \geqslant \frac12$.

---

**Remarks.**

- The median that we defined above is the largest median of $X$. Correspondingly, the smallest median is given by $\inf \ \{ a \mid P(X \leqslant a) \geqslant \frac12 \}$.
- The set of medians of $X$ is a convex set, i.e., interval in $\mathbb R$. Moreover it is also compact (i.e., closed and bounded), because its infimum and supremum are finite and are contained in the set.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think I need more information. Also is the set of medians closed? The one you gave looks like the max median, does it?

Comment: Thanks! So in $\mathbb{R}$, is interval defined as a convex subset?

Comment: No, it's not defined that way, but in $\mathbb R$, these two notions coincide. An interval is defined on a universe with total or partial order; a set $I$ is an interval if whenever $x, z \in I$, $\{ y \mid x < y < z \} \subseteq I$. OTOH a convex set is defined in a (say) vector space. A set $C$ is convex if whenever $x,y \in C$, we have $\{ t x + (1-t)y \mid 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1 \} \subseteq C$.

Comment: Set of medians is a convex set by Jensen's inequality?