# Median of random variable times constant

Tags: probability

Let $\xi$ be a random variable with the median $m_ξ$. Is it true that  $m_{\varepsilon\xi} = \varepsilon m_\xi, \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @StefanHansen if not then a counter-example might be helpful

Comment: @StefanHansen I disagree (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general $m_{\xi}$ serves as median of $\xi$ iff: $$P\left(\xi\leq m_{\xi}\right)\geq0.5\wedge P\left(\xi\geq m_{\xi}\right)\geq0.5\tag1$$

Sidenote: a median is not necessarily unique. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827148/75923) and its answer.

So the question can rephrased as: does $(1)$
imply that: $$P\left(\epsilon\xi\leq\epsilon m_{\xi}\right)\geq0.5\wedge P\left(\epsilon\xi\geq\epsilon m_{\xi}\right)\geq0.5\text{ for every }\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$$?

The answer on this is: yes (also if $\epsilon\leq0$).

Comment: May I ask how to prove the rephrased question?

Comment: If $\epsilon>0$ then $\epsilon\xi\leq\epsilon m_{\xi}\iff\xi\leq m_{\xi}$ and $\epsilon\xi\geq\epsilon m_{\xi}\iff\xi\geq m_{\xi}$ (just divide by $\epsilon$) so we are dealing with the same events. If $\epsilon<0$ then $\epsilon\xi\leq\epsilon m_{\xi}\iff\xi\geq m_{\xi}$ and  $\epsilon\xi\geq\epsilon m_{\xi}\iff\xi\leq m_{\xi}$ (again divide by $\epsilon$ but switch $\geq$ into $\leq$ and vice versa) and again we are dealing with the same events. If $\epsilon=0$ then $P(0\leq0)=P(0\geq0)=1\geq0.5$ where $\epsilon\xi$ is degenerated at $0$ and has $0$ as median.