# Bound on the absolute difference between mean and median of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable such that, for all $t>0$,
$$\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X-M\rvert >t\} \leq a e^{-t^2/b} $$ where $M$ is the median and $a > 0,b >0$.

How can I show that $|M-\mathbb{E}[X]\rvert \leq \sqrt{ab}$?

Comment: You're sure it's not $a\sqrt{b}$?

Comment: Yes, it is $\sqrt{ab}$.  If look here https://www.hse.ru/data/2016/11/24/1113029206/Concentration%20inequalities.pdf  in page number 55.

Comment: I see. So the bound is $\min(\sqrt{ab}, a\sqrt{b\pi}/2)$. My answer shows the second term, $a\sqrt{b\pi}/2$.

Comment: (Te first bound follows on the bound of $\sqrt{\mathrm{var X}}$  (Exercise 2.1 of the book, or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/503760/75808)) provided you manage to show that $\mathrm{var X}\leq ab$.

Comment: yup. I am more interested in the first bound.

Comment: see my edited answer, following the outline from above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proves the stronger bound of $\min\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a\sqrt{b}, \sqrt{ab}\right)$), as asked in the Exercise 2.22 of *Concentration inequalities* by Boucheron, Lugosi, and Massart (2012) referenced by the OP in the comments.

---

- The bound $\frac{\pi}{2}a\sqrt{b}$: 
  as in [this related question (and answer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/503760/75808), start with
  $$
  \left|M[X]-\mathbb{E}(X)\right|=\left|\mathbb{E}[M[X]-X]\right| 
  \leq \mathbb{E} \left|X-M[X]\right| \tag{1}
  $$
  Now, use [the fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value) that, for the random variable $\left|X-M[X]\right| \geq 0$
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left|X-M[X]\right| = \int_{(0,\infty)} \mathbb{P}\{\left|X-M[X]\right| > t\} dt 
  \leq \int_{(0,\infty)} a e^{-t^2/b} dt = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} a\sqrt{b}\,.
  $$
- The bound $\sqrt{ab}$: the aforementioned question (or Exercise 2.21 of the referenced book) establishes that, provided $X$ is squared integrable,
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left|X-M[X]\right|
  \leq \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[X]}
  $$
  so it suffices to show that our assumption proves both that $X$ is squared integrable, and that $\operatorname{Var}[X]\leq ab$. This is done in one step, using the same trick as before:
  $$\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[\left|X-M[X]\right|^2] &= \int_{(0,\infty)} \mathbb{P}\{\left|X-M[X]\right|^2 > t\} dt
  = \int_{(0,\infty)} \mathbb{P}\{\left|X-M[X]\right| > \sqrt{t}\} dt 
  \\&\leq \int_{(0,\infty)} a e^{-(\sqrt{t})^2/b} dt = \int_{(0,\infty)} a e^{-t/b} dt = ab < \infty
  \end{align}$$
  proving both that $X$ is square-integrable, and giving the desired bound (but on $\mathbb{E}[\left|X-M[X]\right|^2]$, not directly $\operatorname{Var}[X]$). Since $\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{Var}[X-M[X]] \leq  \mathbb{E}[\left|X-M[X]\right|^2]$, however, this implies the result.

Comment: I did not understand how you can write  $$
\mathbb{E}\left|X-M[X]\right| = \int_{(0,\infty)} \mathbb{P}\{\left|X-M[X]\right| > t\} dt
$$

Comment: Click on the link to Wikipedia, and look at the alternative expression of the expectation of a non-negative r.v. (this is a very useful "trick" to know, incidentally). @Shew