# Is the solution to Mean Squared Error also the one to Mean Absolute Error?

Tags: statistics, optimization, linear-programming

When I was dealing with optimization problem and deciding whether to minimize MSE or MAE, I had the following question: Is the solution to Mean Squared Error also the one to Mean Absolute Error? If yes, why would we choose one model over the other?

Comment: Have you tried some examples?  Also, check [wikipedia MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error#Related_measures) or [wikipedia MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Criticism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is no. The MAE and MSE problems are not generally equal.**

It generally depends on the type of your problem and what you exactly pursue. For example let the following optimization problems ($x,x_0\in\Bbb R^2$)$${P1: MAE\\\min ||x-x_0||_1\\s.t.\\ ||x||_2=1}$$$${P2: MSE\\\min ||x-x_0||_2\\s.t.\\ ||x||_2=1}$$Both the problems $P_1$ and $P_2$ stand for minimizing the distance between our parameter to a desired value *in some sense*. As an example, let $x_0=(1,2)$. Then the optimal solutions of the two optimization problems are $$x_1^*\approx (0.7071,0.7071)\\x_2^*\approx (0.4472,0.8944)$$which are not equal. Also a plot of the error functions is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in \mathbb R$.

The solution of the MSE problem is  $\text{argmin}_x \sum_{k=1}^n (x_i-x)^2 = \{\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n x_i\}$ which you might know as the sample mean.

The solution of the MAE problem is  $\text{argmin}_x \sum_{k=1}^n |x_i-x| = \{\text{medians of }(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \}$.

In general, the sample mean is not a median of $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, so the solutions of both problems are different.

---

Using [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503710/distance-between-mean-and-median) with the distribution that puts mass $\frac 1n$ on each sample, the difference between the two solutions must be less than $\displaystyle  \sqrt{\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-\overline x)^2}$ where $\overline x = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n x_k$.