# Understanding $ \int_c^\infty (x-c) dF(x) $ through integration by parts

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85450/278372), it is claimed that we can solve the problem in the following way:

$$\displaystyle \int_{c}^{\infty} (x-c) dF(x) = \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} (y-c) F(y) - \displaystyle \int_{c}^{\infty} F(x) dx.$$

where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of a given random variable.

Does this limit exist though? In my understanding, since distribution function saturates at 1, the first limit should converge to infinity? What am I missing?

Comment: @CalvinKhor how is it so, if both $y$ and $P(y)$ are nondecreasing? I will try to wrap my head around it

Comment: Oh I may have misunderstood, is P the cumulative distribution function?

Comment: @CalvinKhor it should be, yes. I agree, the notation is bad for a CDF, copied it from the linked answer. Will edit to avoid confusion, thanks!

Comment: If F is indeed a cumulative distribution function then the second integral is similarly infinite and should cancel the divergence of thr first term ie as in the answer below

Comment: A wrong argument in an answer with 7 upvotes? Just an ordinary day on mse... :-)

Comment: The correct argument is $$ \int_c^\infty (x-c) dF(x) = \lim_{y \to\infty} -(y-c) (1-F(y)) +\int_c^\infty (1-F(x)) dx=\int_c^\infty (1-F(x)) dx$$

Comment: @Did good point. One upvote is mine, since the first part before the edit seems OK (didn't check, but arrived to the answer), though may have to reconsider..:) As for your second comment -- how did you arrive to $(1-F(y))$ part? My quick guess would be $\int (x-c)dF(x) = - \int(x-c)d(1-F(x))$? If so, this seems as a useful trick! Either way, Thanks!

Comment: @Nutle Yes, this is simply $dF=-d(1-F)$ and the notion that $1-F$ is better than $F$ here since with limit zero at +oo.

Comment: @Did finally, sorry if this is a dumb question: $(y-c) \rightarrow \infty$ while $(1-F(y)) \rightarrow 0$. Unless $1-F(y)$ decays exponentially (or with $>1$ power?), how can we be sure that it reaches $0$ faster than $\infty$? Or is$\infty \cdot 0 = 0$? Though on the other hand, I can't imagine such $F$ to contradict that result.

Comment: The question is not dumb in the least. It happens that, by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, $(y-c)(1-F(y))\to0$ as soon as $X$ is integrable (actually, $X^+$ integrable).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the formula be,

$\displaystyle \int_c^\infty dP(x) = \lim_{y\to\infty} \left\{ (y-c) P(y) - \int_c^y P(x) dx \right\} $

Then for large $ x $, $ P(x) $ approaches 1, and you end up with both terms approaching $\infty$.

Not very helpful in finding the answer but perhaps explains the confusion.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, missed that the second term would approach $-\infty$ too. Still, it indeed does not seem helpful. Unless trying simplifying the formula you used for fixed $y$, and the limit might look nicer if some terms could get cancelled out?