# Showing that $(y-c)(1-F(y)) \underset{y \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 0$ for $F$ the cdf of an integrable random variable?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was reading the comments in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3045074/understanding-int-c-infty-x-c-dfx-through-integration-by-parts) and it was suggested that this limit is $0$ by dominated convergence theorem. I'm not able to see how. If anyone sees it and could give some hints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $yP(Y>y)\to 0$ as $y\to\infty$ as $cP(Y>y)\to 0$ is clear. To see this note that for $y>0$
$$
0\leq yI(Y>y)\leq YI(Y>y).
$$
Take expectations to yield that
$$
yP(Y>y)\leq E(YI(Y>y))\to 0
$$
as $y\to \infty$ by the dominated convergence theorem.