# $m$ minimizes $E(|X-a|)$ over $a\in R$ if and only if $m$ is a median for $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to show that $E(|X-a|)$ attains its minimum value if and only if $a=m$ where $m$ is the median. I know this particular problem has been discussed before, but I want to prove it in a specific way which I could not find elsewhere.

**My attempt:**

Assume $m\neq a$ and suppose $m<a$

If $X<m<a$, then $|X-a|-|X-m|=(a-X)-(m-X)=a-m$

If $m<X<a$, then $|X-a|-|X-m|=(a-X)-(X-m)=a+m-2X$

If $m<a<X$ ,then $|X-a|-|X-m|=(X-a)-(X-m)=m-a$

Now, I want to deductively show that $E(|X-a|)-E(|X-m|)>0$ However, I'm not sure how to go about solving this. Can anyone please chime in?

And clearly, once, I solve this, I can symmetrically solve the case where $m>a$ the same way.

Comment: See this solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2790390/215011 It is using your approach, with $m=0$

Answer (score 2):

Using (a slight modification of) the above characterisation, show that for $m <a,$ $$\mathbb{E}[|X-a| - |X-m|] = (a-m) ( P(X \le m) - P(X > a) ) + \mathbb{E}[(a + m - 2X)\mathbf{1}\{ X \in (m, a] \}].$$ You can further lower bound this by $$ (a-m) ( P(X \le m) - P(X > m) ) = (a-m) (2P(X \le m) - 1)$$ by noticing that for $X \in (m,a], a +m - 2X \ge -(a-m)$.

Now, $a - m > 0$, and by the definition of the median, $P(X \le m) \ge 1/2.$ Note that you cannot in general get a strict inequality - this is because the median need not be unique. To get this needs more work.

---

Since you wanted the first equality explained (this is just the argument angryavian poses, carried out in detail).

first, I'll edit your characterisation a little by making the first case be $X\le m$ and the second be $m < X \le a$. This clearly doesn't alter anything.

Now, for succinctness, let $f(X) := |X-a| - |X-m|.$  \begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] &= \mathbb{E}[f(X) \mathbf{1}\{X \le m\}] + \mathbb{E}[f(X) \mathbf{1}\{m < X \le a\}] + \mathbb{E}[f(X) \mathbf{1}\{X > a\}]  
\end{align}

Now, for $X \le m,$ $f(X) = a-m$. Similarly in other domains. Using htis, we have $$ \mathbb{E}[f(X)] = (a-m) \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}\{X \le m\}] + \mathbb{E}[f(X) \mathbf{1}\{m < X \le a\}] + \mathbb{E}[ (m-a) \mathbf{1}\{X > a\}]. $$

Now just note that $a-m$ is a constant, and that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}\{X \in E\}] = P(X \in E)$.

Comment: Would you be able to explain the first equality?

Comment: @YaG From the work that you already did, you have shown $|X-a| - |X-m| = (a-m) 1_{X < m} + (a+m - 2X)1_{m < X \le a} + (m-a) 1_{X>a}$. Take the expectation of both sides to get stochasticboy321's first line.