# $X$ can be written as $\int_0^\infty\textbf{1}_{\{X>x\}}dx-\int_0^\infty\textbf{1}_{\{-X>x\}}dx$

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, proof-writing, random-variables

I want to prove that if $X$ is a random variable, then
$$X=\int_0^\infty\textbf{1}_{\{X>x\}}dx-\int_0^\infty\textbf{1}_{\{-X>x\}}dx$$
[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85453/758031) answer and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295742/153166) answer use this result and I don't understand why can we write $X$ this way. Can someone tell me where to find proof of this? Or help me with it?

Comment: By the way, the fact that $X$ is a random variable is irrelevant here. The same fact holds for any real number $X$.

Comment: @JamesMartin a real number is still a random variable, but a constant one

Comment: Sure. I am just pointing out that the property you are asking about doesn't rely on anything about random variables or probability in any way. It's true for any number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $X\geq 0$ then $\int_0^\infty\textbf{1}_{\{-X>x\}}dx=0$ and

$$
\int_0^\infty\textbf{1}_{\{X>x\}}dx = \int_0^{X}\,dx =X
$$
if $X<0$ then $\int_0^\infty\textbf{1}_{\{X>x\}}dx=0$ and
$$
\int_0^\infty\textbf{1}_{\{-X>x\}}dx = \int_0^{-X}dx =-X.
$$

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Could you help me write $|X|$ in this format, please?

Comment: $|X|$ is always non-negative, so you can just use the first equation.

Comment: I know, but I would like to express the indicator function in terms of $X$ instead of $|X|$. I guess I would have to split the integral in two, since here I don't know if $X$ is non-negative. But I'm not sure how to do it. I think it would be: $$|X|=X_+ + X_-=\int_0^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{X>x\}}+\int_0^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{-X>x\}}$$ And also: $$X-c= \int_{-c}^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{X>x\}}-\int_{-c}^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{-X>x\}}$$ Is this right?

Comment: The first one is certainly right but the second one does not seem correct (think about the ranges of these integral a little bit more).

Comment: It should be this right?: $$X-c=\int_0^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{X-c>x\}}-\int_0^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{-X+c>x\}}=\int_0^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{X>x+c\}}-\int_0^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{-X>x-c\}}=\int_c^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{X>x\}}-\int_c^\infty \textbf{1}_{\{-X>x\}}$$

Comment: The last integral should have a range $-c$ to $\infty$.